# JavaScript history.go and load balancer question

Tags: javascript, forms, load-balancing

I have a web application that I have recently place behind a load balancer.  There is a page that has the javascript:history.go(-1) method in a link.  The previous page is a form that performs a submit.  When I click on the link that performs the go method, going to the server directly, does not try to resubmit the form.  But when I click on the same link through the load balancer the form does a resubmit.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to perform this task through a load balancer so the link does not resubmit the page?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be caused by not having "sticky sessions" enabled in the Load Balancer.  It wouldn't know the resulting page load from the `go` is coming from the same user, so instead of simply displaying the page, it's re-serving it.

Do you know if it has "sticky sessions" enabled or if that's an option?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern for the "previous" page. In other words - process the POST request and instead of returning a result redirect to another page. It will be loaded using GET and the form won't be re-submitted upon navigating back to it.